# Comparing items in different data files with shared identifier in Liquid/Jekll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm building a Jekyll site that has a page that displays product information from a JSON file. I was wondering if it would be possible to filter what products are displayed by the corresponding quantity listed in another CSV file with stock numbers. Both of these files use the same identifier for each product. E.G. something along the lines of:

```
{% for product in site.data.products %}
  {% if product.identifier == stock.identifier and current-stock < X %}
    Display the product
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [where](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/) filter :

```
<ul>
{% for product in site.data.products %}
  <li>
    {% assign id = product.identifier %}
    {% assign data = site.data.stock | where: "identifier", id | first %}

    {% if data %}
      {{ data | inspect }}
    {% else %}
      No data available
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```